# Unity 5.6 2D- How can I check if 2 colliders isn't touching any other collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

In Unity 5.6 C#, I know there is a way to check for if a collider is being touched by any other collider by using IsTouching.

However, I would like to know how to group two colliders together(that are touching each other), and how to check if they both are touching any collider besides each other.

Comment: Keep collisions in a list, check if both collide with anything else then their according "partner"

Comment: @derHugo , How would I do that? IsTouching returns a boolean

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter` -> add collider to the List; `OnCollisionExit` -> Remove that collider from the List => everything in the List is currently touching. => `if(collisions.Count == 1)` you know there is only 1 "partner" touching this object. Now you only need to check if the other object also has only 1 touch and if you are this object.

Comment: You could also put the colliders in a layer and set a layer mask using `contactFilter`

Comment: @derHugo They are both attached to the same GameObject and are both BoxColliders, will this complicate anything?

Comment: Actually it makes it easier I guess .. you will only need one script then right?

Comment: @derHugo As it turns out, it does complicate things. By slamming one collider(head) into the other(body) against the different collider(ceiling), the collider detection thinks there is always one touching.

Comment: @derHugo If you want to help me more, check my profile for the full explanation or follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440776/for-some-reason-collider-check-has-extra-collider

Comment: Ad said before: don't use IsTouching but rather a list of colliders. Since both colliders are on the same GameObject you can easily filter them: `OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) { if(col.gameObject == gameObject) return; colliderList.Add(col.collider); }` then you can have you own `isTouching` implementation which returns `bool isTouching => colliderList.Count != 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give it a shot with the idea I mentioned in the comments (I see it is hard to understand with only the comments section).

I would use a list of collisions and store any touches here, filtering out the "partner" collider using [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html).

Since both are attached to the same GameObject it is easy to filter them:

```
public class Collisions : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Show in the Inspector for debug
    [SerializeField] private List<Collider> colliderList = new List<Collider>();

    public bool IsTouching => colliderList.Count != 0;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Make sure list is empty at start
        colliderList.Clear();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        // Filter out own collider
        if(collision.gameObject == gameObject) return;

        if(!colliderList.Contains(collision.collider) colliderList.Add(collision.collider);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        // Filter out own collider
        if(collision.gameObject == gameObject) return;

        if(colliderList.Contains(collision.collider) colliderList.Remove(collision.collider);
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thanks for this, but I found a workaround(so I can keep the 2 colliders and have a wallhang by being able to detect the partner collider's collisions. Not sure if your code does that too.) Anyway, I did use your OnCollisionEnter and Exit idea, so you were a big help! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is what I used :)
`{
        if (AirDetect == 3)
        {
            AirDetect = 2;
            AirDetect2 = 2;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    { 
        AirDetect = AirDetect + 1;

        AirDetect2 = AirDetect2 + 1;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        AirDetect = AirDetect - 1;

        AirDetect2 = AirDetect2 - 1;
    }`