# For some reason, colliders collide, and I can fly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, collider

I am making a small prototype of a Unity 2D game. I have 2 colliders for my character. This helps me because I want my character to be able to wall jump. This means that when I collide with the wall, my collider detection script assumes that I am hitting 2 colliders, and helps me customize animations.

```
     //on the ground, change y position as necessary, and if you are pressing up, held = true
     if (InAirDetection.AirDetect == 1)
     {

         position.y += MoveUnitsPerSecond * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
         if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") == true)
         {
             held = true;
         }
         position.y += MoveUnitsPerSecond * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
     }

     //on the wall, change y position as neccessary, and if you are pressing up, held = true
     if (InAirDetection.AirDetect == 2)
     {

         position.y += MoveUnitsPerSecond * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
         if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") == true)
         {
             held = true;
         }
     }


     //in the air, if held is true, change y. If you aren't pressing up, held is false.
     if (InAirDetection.AirDetect == 0)
     {
         if (held == true)
         {
             position.y += MoveUnitsPerSecond * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
         }
         if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") == false)
         {
             held = false;
         }
     }

 }
 // apply the transformations
 transform.position = position;
```

This is some of my code. I tried to make it so that if I let go of up in the air and pressed it again and nothing would happen. It works but there is a slight problem...

By slamming one collider(head) against the different collider(ceiling), the head goes into the body collider. This makes the collider detection thinks there is always one collider touching and that I am holding up. That means that I can jump about 5 times the intended height. Another side effect is that sometimes there seems to be a force acting on one the side of the object, like wind. This doesn't always happen.

How can I remove the bug completely? Is my only option to make the character have 1 collider?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have one collider and tag the walls (or put them on one layer) then check if the collider is touching a wall?

Comment: You could exclude those two Colliders from detecting each other. I have no idea how do that in Unity, however.

Comment: @Christopher, I wanted to figure that out too, haha.

Comment: @jmalenfant, Having one collider would make it hard to customize animations or the way the sprite poses. However, if you have a solution for that as well, I wouldn't mind using your answer.

Comment: @Christopher
derHugo was able to find out how here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439562/unity-5-6-2d-how-can-i-check-if-2-colliders-isnt-touching-any-other-collider
Luckily, I found a workaround anyway, so no worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an extra line of code. Also, I changed the collider's position a tad bit. 
This was the extra line:

`position.y += MoveUnitsPerSecond * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;`

Also, my AirDetection was flawed, but I fixed that, so everything's good to go!
Now, however, if I hold it and jump(or jump, let go, and hit up again before hitting the ground), I jump an extra 1.8/1.9 units higher. That's ok though.